# Add CSS class on text align

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'd like to add CSS class or set a style for an image when I click align right, left or center in my "CKEditor" in Drupal 7.

What should I do? I can make a plugin, but I don't know how to catch text align operation to add the class/set style on an image.

Comment: I found plugin called justify but it works only on <p> not on <img>. Does anybody know how to edit settings to add class to <img> tag?

Answer (score 2):

There are CKEditor configurations that allow you to use class-based alignment for images and text justification for paragraphs instead of using inline CSS added to the style attribute.  You'll need to paste this into the "Custom JavaScript configuration" of the "Advanced Options" section of the CKEditor profile(s) you're working with in Drupal admin UI:

```
// Image alignment and text justification.
config.justifyClasses = [ 'rteleft', 'rtecenter', 'rteright', 'rtejustify' ];
```

If you're ok with giving up the old Image properties dialog, the [Enhanced Image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2) plugin for CKEditor has the ability to [use classes for image alignment](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_captionedimage-section-image-alignment-and-classes) instead of inline CSS on the `<img>` tag's style attribute, however this non-default configuration must be added to the "Advanced Options" section by hand, and you'll also need to provide your own stylesheet else the images will not align in the editor nor on the front-end of your site.

```
// Image alignment classes for Enhanced Image plugin.
config.image2_alignClasses = [ 'align-left', 'align-center', 'align-right' ];
```

Alternatively, the module [CKEditor Image2](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/jwilson3/2454995) handles these required modifications to the Advanced Options and provides a stylesheet you can use out of the box.

Disclaimer: I'm creator and maintainer of CKEditor Image2 module. Feedback welcome.

Comment: just right at what I'm looking for. tried to edit it source code but to hard in the code jungle, so it's much greater when it allow to use class instead of inline

Answer (score 0):

You can give your own classes/styles to image that uploaded through ckeditor. In ckeditor image upload popup window, you can see three options/tabs
1. Image Info
2. Link
3. Advanced

[image]

You can add id, classes, styles etc on selecting the Advanced option.

Comment: Thank You for answer, but I'd like to do it with one click without editing image's proporties. For example: allign to right will add class allign-right.